# kill the application in Iphone

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, sigkill

To kill an application in simulator, I do

> double click on the home button then the red badge appears, tap it to
>   kill the app

After that, i return to the the screen and double click to relaunch an application and i got

> Thread 1 : program received signal :"SIGKILL"

I tried about 5 application download from sample codes at Apple and I got the same problem... Have I done something wrong or else. Please advice me on this issue
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong here. What happens is the simulator is giving you the reason the application was stopped the last time. To restart the app, simply CMD+Q to quit the simulator, or use the stop button in XCode.